# how to redirect to two url from jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, url-routing, response.redirect

I'm working on the `OTP verification` where I have to call two URL in which the first page is `SMS sending URL` and the second one goes to the page where the user has to `enter the received OTP`.How Can I Do This? I Use `response.sendRedirect` but it can't work with two URL.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to **redirect** request to two pages.
Just revisit your workflow:

1. User tries to reach some page it requires OTP
2. You have to send SMS - at that point is there a page for the user to select which phone to send or is it behind the scene call?

a. there is a page - so it is a first redirect to that one. Then user picks a phone number and click OK - it goes to JSP/Servlet which sends an SMS and then redirect user to the next page where user has to put OTP code.

b. it is a call to send SMS behind the scene, so your JSP makes a fork call to send SMS and redirect user straight to the second page where user hast to put OTP.

In general - it is better to handle "send SMS" from your Server code, rather than push it to the user browser. It is unneeded hop over network (or even two of them)

If you still want user browser to hit "send SMS message" URL - do it there somehow, as example from Javascript Ajax call, "auto-redirect" or such.

Note: Keep in mind auto-redirect means that your "Send SMS" URL must send back to the browser another Redirect to final page where user has to put OTP code.

Comment: I does not mention above but that I do not have any access to page of SMS sending URL page. my SMS gateway provider, provide me that link to send SMS to a user.

Comment: I expected that. Usually it is a 3-rd party service. Anyway there is no place for 2 redirects and there is no such thing anywhere. Communication between browser and server is "One request -> one response". So, just go in proper direction and forget about "two redirects" - it is wrong path to think about it.